# Fetching CORS request in service worker

Tags: cors, service-worker

I'm writing a service worker with the purpose of monitoring a website's traffic. I capture the request and the response and send data about it to my backend

I'm trying to avoid monitoring the CORS requests.
My logic is something like this (dropped not relevant lines):

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event));
});

const handleRequest = async event => {
  let response;
  let request = event.request.clone();
    if (! isCrossOrigin(event.request)) {  
      response = await fetch(event.request);
      storeData(request, response.clone());
      return response;
    } else {
      console.log(`Dropping request for ${event.request.url}`)
      return fetch(request);
    }
};
```

The problem is that when I have a CORS request and I'm fetching it via the `fetch(request)`, without changing original credentials state, I'm getting:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://other-domain.com/test-post' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

I can't send the request without the credentials because my client (the one who's using my service worker) might need it.

I can't return a value other than `*` in the header simply because I don't own the 3rd party origin server. I can't ask to change their API for my monitoring.

My question - Is there a way to just pass on the request as if it wasn't intercepted by my service worker?

I don't mind ignoring CORS requests since they are not critical for what I'm monitoring.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you return from the FetchEvent handler synchronously then the browser will proceed to process it as it normally would.  So something like:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  if (isCrossOrigin(event.request)) {
    return;
  }
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event));
});

const handleRequest = async event => {
  let response = await fetch(event.request);
  storeData(request, response.clone());
  return response;
};
```

This doesn't really address why you're getting an error calling `fetch(evt.request)` from the service worker.  That should in general work if the normal request would have succeeded.

Comment: This looks like a good solution for skipping captured CORS requests. Still pretty curious if there is a way to execute them properly without failing. If there is no better answer I will test it and award this one.

Comment: It would help to have an example site that demonstrates the problem.  Per the spec I believe the given code should work assuming the request would normally have succeeded without the service worker.  There may be a browser bug you are running into.

Comment: The thing is that the same request fails when using `fetch` but succeed when using the old XMLHttpRequest. Why does `fetch` behave differently from XMLHttpRequest? The request is a CORS PUT request (credentials included) from origin A to server B when B returns * in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header - you can reproduce it in Chrome console.

Comment: What initiates the FetchEvent for this request?  Is the main page doing a form post, an XHR, something else?

Comment: Hi, it's an XHR

Comment: @BenKelly , that is a good question. The root of this problem is that listening to fetch events also captures xhr requests that can't be replayed with fetch. What is the best practice here?

Comment: I tried doing any XHR setting `xhr.withCredentials=true` and I get the same wildcard failure even when there is no service worker present.  See this screenshot: https://imageshack.com/i/pnWGq8mlp

Comment: Thanks @BenKelly . I will try to create a self-contained example site to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. Did anyone make any progress as to why this is happening?